# Difference between Library and framework in deep learning

Tags: tensorflow, frameworks, pytorch, difference

I am having a big time difficulty understanding whether TensorFlow/Pytorch is a framework or a library, because they say its an AI/ML opensource framework but in some of the blogs I read it is a library. Could someone please help me with this and also what is the basic difference between framework and library?

Comment: Framework contains from libraries. In other words,framework is wider version of library.